# COGONS - sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-56

Tags: sql-server, report, cognos

I have the following code:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EVT_CODE) AS rn,
        E.EVT_ORG AS Org,
        E.EVT_CODE AS OT, 
        E.EVT_OBJECT AS Equipo, O.OBJ_POSITION AS Posicion, 
        E.EVT_JOBTYPE AS Tipo, 
        E.EVT_DESC AS Descripcion,
        E.EVT_WORKADDRESS AS Comentarios, 
        E.EVT_REQM AS Error, B.BOO_PERSON AS Trabajador, 
        B.BOO_ENTERED AS Fecha, B.BOO_HOURS AS Horass
    FROM
        dbo.r5events AS E 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.r5bookedhours AS B ON E.EVT_CODE = B.BOO_EVENT 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.r5objects AS O ON O.OBJ_CODE = E.EVT_OBJECT
    WHERE   
        E.EVT_JOBTYPE IN ('PM', 'CM', 'PMM') and
        E.EVT_ORG = #PROMPT('Organización')# and
        B.BOO_ENTERED between #PROMPT('Fecha_Inicio')# and #PROMPT('Fecha_Final')# and 
        (E.EVT_REQM = #PROMPT('Error')# OR #PROMPT('Error')# = '%') and
        (E.EVT_OBJECT = #PROMPT('Equipo')# OR #PROMPT('Equipo')# = '%') and
        (O.OBJ_POSITION = #PROMPT('Posicion')# OR #PROMPT('Posicion')# = '%')
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BOO_event) AS rn,
        BOO_event 'Evento de Trabajo',
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(BOO_person AS VARCHAR(100)) [text()]    
               FROM r5bookedhours 
               WHERE BOO_event = t.BOO_event
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(4000)'),1,1,' ') Empleados, 
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(BOO_hours AS VARCHAR(100)) [text()]       
               FROM r5bookedhours 
               WHERE BOO_event = t.BOO_event
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(4000)'), 1, 1, ' ') Horas
    FROM r5bookedhours t
    GROUP BY BOO_event
)
SELECT Org, Empleados, Horas from CTE1 FULL JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.rn = CTE2.rn
```

And it's working fine on SQL Server 2008, but when I try to execute it on COGNOS Report Studio, I'm getting this error:

> 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-56
>
> UDA-SQL-0115 Solicitud SQL no
>   válida.UDA-SQL-0564 [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server]Deferred
>   prepare could not be completed.UDA-SQL-0564 [Microsoft OLE DB Provider
>   for SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (SQLSTATE=42000,
>   SQLERRORCODE=8180)UDA-SQL-0564 [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. (SQLSTATE=42000,
>   SQLERRORCODE=102)UDA-SQL-0564 [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (SQLSTATE=42000,
>   SQLERRORCODE=102)UDA-SQL-0564 [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is
>   a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change
>   tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated
>   with a semicolon. (SQLSTATE=42000, SQLERRORCODE=319)UDA-SQL-0564
>   [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'WITH'. (SQLSTATE=42000, SQLERRORCODE=156)RSV-SRV-0042
>   Rastreo:RSReportService.cpp(722): QFException: CCL_CAUGHT:
>   RSReportService::process()RSReportServiceMethod.cpp(263): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: RSReportServiceMethod::process():
>   promptPagingForward_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(808):
>   QFException:
>   RSASyncExecutionThread::checkExceptionRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(260):
>   QFException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSASyncExecutionThread::runImpl():
>   promptPagingForward_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(864):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSASyncExecutionThread::processCommand():
>   promptPagingForward_RequestExecution/RSRenderExecution.cpp(670):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSRenderExecution::executeAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(291):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSLayoutAssembly.cpp(79):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSLayoutAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSReportPagesAssembly.cpp(179):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSReportPagesAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSPageAssembly.cpp(303):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSPageAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableRowAssembly.cpp(177):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableRowAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableCellAssembly.cpp(137):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableCellAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(662):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSAssembly::createListIteratorAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(717):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSAssembly::createListIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1055): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::getListIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1131):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::getResultSetIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1295): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::createIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1569):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::executeRsapiCommandRSQueryMgr.cpp(1559): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::executeRsapiCommandRSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl.cpp(168):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl::execute()RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl.cpp(160):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl::execute()QFSSession.cpp(1147):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1145): QFException:
>   CCL_CAUGHT: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1102):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1078): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSConnection.cpp(788):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSConnection::ExecuteQFSQuery.cpp(213):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSQuery::Execute
>   v2CoordinationQFSQuery.cpp(4456): QFException: CCL_THROW:
>   CoordinationPlanner

Already tried to simplify the select with only 3 columns, and to simplify the querys with less camps to be selected, but the error keeps showing.

Second Error:

> UDA-SQL-0115 Solicitud SQL no válida.UDA-SQL-0564 [Microsoft OLE DB
>   Provider for SQL Server]Deferred prepare could not be
>   completed.UDA-SQL-0564 [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (SQLSTATE=42000,
>   SQLERRORCODE=8180)UDA-SQL-0564 [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. (SQLSTATE=42000,
>   SQLERRORCODE=102)UDA-SQL-0564 [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near ';'. (SQLSTATE=42000,
>   SQLERRORCODE=102)RSV-SRV-0042 Rastreo:RSReportService.cpp(722):
>   QFException: CCL_CAUGHT:
>   RSReportService::process()RSReportServiceMethod.cpp(263): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: RSReportServiceMethod::process():
>   promptPagingForward_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(808):
>   QFException:
>   RSASyncExecutionThread::checkExceptionRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(260):
>   QFException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSASyncExecutionThread::runImpl():
>   promptPagingForward_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(864):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSASyncExecutionThread::processCommand():
>   promptPagingForward_RequestExecution/RSRenderExecution.cpp(670):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSRenderExecution::executeAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(291):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSLayoutAssembly.cpp(79):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSLayoutAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSReportPagesAssembly.cpp(179):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSReportPagesAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSPageAssembly.cpp(303):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSPageAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableRowAssembly.cpp(177):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableRowAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableCellAssembly.cpp(137):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableCellAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(662):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSAssembly::createListIteratorAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(717):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSAssembly::createListIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1055): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::getListIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1131):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::getResultSetIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1295): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::createIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1569):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::executeRsapiCommandRSQueryMgr.cpp(1559): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::executeRsapiCommandRSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl.cpp(168):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl::execute()RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl.cpp(160):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl::execute()QFSSession.cpp(1147):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1145): QFException:
>   CCL_CAUGHT: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1102):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1078): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSConnection.cpp(788):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSConnection::ExecuteQFSQuery.cpp(213):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSQuery::Execute
>   v2CoordinationQFSQuery.cpp(4456): QFException: CCL_THROW:
>   CoordinationPlanner

Comment: Do you CTE's queries work fine separately?

Comment: Yes, they work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tired of everything, created 2 views and was the end of my problems... way easier. Thanks all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
>   context clause, **the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.**

Always add semicolon before and after like:

```
;WITH 
  ...
SELECT ...;
```

**EDIT:**

Make `SELECT` exactly after cte

```
;WITH cte AS 
(


)
SELECT ...
```

Comment: That changed the error message. Now I get the second one (edited the main post).

Comment: @Nanaki What is `#PROMPT('Organización')#` syntax?

Comment: The #PROMPT syntax is just a question for the user running the report to filter data, its like ='10', for example. 

Updated the code with your new syntax, but the same error shows up :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix TSQL and COGNOS specific features IMHO. Whereas WITH is a valid TSQL common table expression, #PROMPT is a feature of Cognos-SQL.

Comment: WITH is a feature of TSQL. Is your query marked as pass-through?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: add order by clause in the final select statement. and Tadaaa!